# Prestashop - Send data from Add to cart to orders summary in the Back Office

Tags: php, module, controller, prestashop

I created a module for customers to customize a product. They access the module from a button in the product page, which send them to a new page where they'll get the product as a customizable SVG element.

Then, they can add the product to shopping cart and order it the classic way.

Just when the customer click on the Add to cart button, I want to get the customized SVG element and integrate it to the cart and order (mainly the order) and so be able to display and download this element in the Back Office in the orders summary.

I tried adding the element to the Cart object but when I get back this object with the right ID in the cart in the BO, the object is empty.

Do somebody as something for that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will be pretty complicated and time-consuming.

I suggest you look at the default customization mechanism in PrestaShop. You can upload different images as a customization. You can't upload .svg files. Your job would be to:

- integrate with the default mechanism
- implement .svg support for it

It's a complex job, and a probably better idea is to look for a module that would do that for you. Reinventing the wheel there may not have a good ROI :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the thing is the module is already done. I spent 2 months on it. The last thing I need is to pass a string from the module's front page to the orders summary in the BO.
For the rest, everything is good.

Comment: You should keep the data related to your module in your modules' table with the relation to `id_cart`.Then, you can hook into the back office page where the order is displayed, get `id_order`, and from the instance of the `Order`, you can get `id_cart`.

Here's an example module which could help you: https://github.com/PrestaShop/example-modules/tree/master/demovieworderhooks

Comment: Very interesting, I'll have a look on this idea.
I just created a new subject with more precisions on what I'm currently trying to do on Prestashop's forum if you want to see : https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1068470-value-in-cart-object-deleted-when-carrier-is-chosen-i-need-to-pass-the-value-from-cart-to-order/